# PHP MySQL insert in float(3,1) always get "0" as decimal

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, decimal

I want to insert this value in a FLOAT(3,1) column in my Database:

```
$sec['votos_rating'] = 5 + ($sec['votos_pos'] * (5 / $sec['votos_total'])) - ($sec['votos_neg'] * (5 / $sec['votos_total']));
```

But I always get `1.0`, `2.0`, `3.0`, etc...

Do you know what could I be doing wrong?

This was the problem:

```
    $db->addInteger('votos_rating', $sec['votos_rating']);
```

I should have used addFloat instead... ;)

Comment: does it have anything to do with the PDO statement to attach the variables to the query?  $db->addInteger ?

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell Yes, I just noticed... Do you know what should I use instead? ;)

Comment: Well, what database library are you using?

Comment: Based on the other statements, I'd guess 'addFloat'.

Comment: SORRY, can I delete this question? I'm embarassed :$

Comment: @Santiago, yes you can, but it won't help other people who are having the same issue.  You can use bindValue and just bind the value to your sql handle.  This way you don't have to worry about the types.

Comment: @David If you want to add an answer I will accept your answer for your help!

Comment: @Santiago I added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `addFloat($val)` to achieve the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Can it be that you using $db->addInteger?